# .NET Core MVC - Add roles to AzureAD User from local database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, user-roles

I have setup a .NET Core 2.0 MVC application which is using AzureAD Authentication (multi-tenant). This works as expected... Login/Password dialog from Microsoft is showing up. As I understand, everybody with a work or school-account can login to this application.

Now I want to assign User-Roles based on my local app-database. I created a class "User" with properties for Login (email) and Role and corresponding controller/views.

What would be the best way to assign these roles to the user that is currently logged in? I do not want to use AzureAD for role-assignment.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this issue?